# How to access Roles and permissions to generic views

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, permissions, roles

I am very new to Django. Right now I am working on Roles and Permission with Django rest framwork. I have discovered 
https://django-role-permissions.readthedocs.io/en/stable/setup.html

By using this I can check roles and permission. But when going in generic views like `generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` I don't want to override the three methods. Is any way can I implement with DRY principle or any best practice.

Is any way URL restrictions based on user roles and permission or any before action for views?

Comment: Have you tried used has_permission method decorator to your url in urls.py or in your view by creating a custom authentication and permission class and extending it in your generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView class ?

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: I suggest you to extend the `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` and set the `permission_classes` attribute.